# SSH Port Forwarding Service

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

My home computer is behind a firewall that I do not control and blocks all (yes, all) inbound traffic.  Nearly any outbound traffic (and replies associated with it) are allowed, though.  I would like to have SSH access to my machine.  Given a friendly server on the Internet, I could use SSH itself to forward a port on the remote server to port 22 on the home computer, essentially using the remote computer as a secure proxy.

I do not have such a friendly server.  Does there exist a service that offers to port forward in this manner?

Comment: You can use any remote machine capable of SSH to set up a reverse tunnel. A VPS would work, or you can get an Amazon EC2 instance - it's free for a year and about $10/month thereafter, I think. I don't know of any more specific free service, but maybe someone else can answer that.

Comment: https://tunnelin.com doing just what you want. It will forward a port on its server to your local server's 22 (basically to any port), moreover, it will give you an easily configurable firewall to limit access by time, IP, and requests count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several services that provide exactly that - free SSH port forwarding

Here is a brief list:

- [sshto.net](https://www.sshto.net) - the simplest free SSH port forwarding service you can find based on just plain ssh
- [openport.io](https://openport.io) - a more sophisticated service that requires you to install their client software and has professional plans
- [neorouter.com](http://neorouter.com/) - an even more feature packed and pricey software that also packs VPN support
- [remot3.it](https://www.remot3.it/web/remot3-it-is-the-new-weaved.html) - a platform that is focused on IoT but does provide similar features
- [dataplicity.com](https://www.dataplicity.com/) - a small easy platform specifically designed to access your Raspberry PI shell which may help if you access your home network from an RPI

Answer (score 2):

@user55325 gave a good advice, of course. Still, you can get away with a free service, provided you are satisfied with less than Amazon EC2 has to offer. The sites listed [on this Web page](http://shells.red-pill.eu/) provide *free* shells, which are certainly enough if all you intend to do is to set up a reverse ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Zerotier](https://my.zerotier.com/) helpful for accessing machines behind firewall. It is free for personal use, up to 50 machines.

It does need local clients to be installed on all your machines.